# Change Visual Studio 2017 Theme Color for Parameter Name Hint (ReSharper)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, themes, resharper, vs-color-theme-editor

We are using `ReSharper` and have the parameter name hint turned on, but in my custom theme its hard to read:
[image: Parameter Name Hint]

I am using the Theme Editor and have looked through all the `ReSharper` settings and searched for parameter name hint but nothing is coming up so it must be a more generic setting.

Does anyone know what setting controls the parameter name hint so I can change the foreground or background color to make it more readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by changing the 'ReSharper Parameter Name Hint' display item under `Tools`->`Options`->`Environment`->`Fonts and Colors` in Visual Studio:

[image]

**Update:** This setting may have moved to 'Resharper Inlay Hint' according to [this](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004188159-Parameter-Name-Hints-Color-Scheme-is-Thrown-Off) but I can't confirm as I am not running ReSharper 2019.3.

Comment: What version of ReSharper are you using? I am using 2019.2.3

Comment: This setting may have moved to 'Resharper Inlay Hint'.

Comment: Yep that is where it was! THanks!

Comment: I confirm that this has been moved to 'Resharper Inlay Hint'

Answer (score 0):

Piers Myers, for some reason I dont have that option listed in Display Items:

[image]

This is my ReSharper version:
[image]

So not sure why that option is not listed. If I click on ReSharper->Options->Editor->Inlay Hints it shows Parameter Name Hint options:

[image]

Comment: Add this info to a comment or update your original question as this is not an answer to your question.