# Change color of argument highlight

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How to change color of arguments hints as shown below? The one with white.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are really using ReSharper; that feature is not part of Visual Studio as far as I know.

From JetBrains' [website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html), at the bottom of the link:

> You can configure the color of inlay hints in Visual Studio options —
>   go to Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors and find the
>   ReSharper Inlay Hint in the list of display items.

Comment: also this is a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777811/change-visual-studio-2017-theme-color-for-parameter-name-hint-resharper

Answer (score 1):

Go to Visual Studio Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors and scroll down to Inline Hints, change Item background and foreground

Answer (score 0):

No need to spend money for that IMHO.

For VS 2019, you can go with [Enhanced Syntax Highlighting
extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StanislavKuzmichArtStea1th.EnhancedSyntaxHighlighting).

Comment: Agreed about no need to spend money, but isn't that answering a different question?  I suppose we don't know for sure if ReSharper is used unless @Arie confirms it.  But assuming so, the question is how to change the color, not 'what's the best/cheapest way to show argument hints?'.

Comment: @SeanSkelly I'm not a **developer**, I'm being an **engineer** means I have to consider efficiency at most. Further, it is my idea at his discretion.